# No puedo mover objetos en la pantalla en android studio

Tags: android-studio

Hola Soy nuevo en android estudio y no me deja arrastrar y solatar objetos desde la paleta a la pantalla, solo puedo agregarlos con click derecho y add to design , el problema es que tampoco me deja mover los objetos en la pantalla con el mouse, asi trate de ampliarlos o moverlos con el mouse no se dejan mover , porfavor alguien que me ayude gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto va a parecer una respuesta tonta, pero has probado a reiniciar el programa? A veces se suele quedar pillado.

Comment: Hola , ya lo intente , pero no se deja mover , los objetos en la pantalla , es como si estuviera bloqueada la opcion , de todos modos gracias por responder

Comment: Has intentado insertar otro componente? En plan un TextBox, un label... para ver si te sucede lo mismo. Otra prueba que puedes hacer es crear un proyecto nuevo y ver si te ocurre nuevamente el mismo fallo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se que ha pasado tiempo desde que se hizo esta pregunta, pero soy nuevo en Android, tuve el mismo problema, y no encontré ninguna solución en la web. Al final la solución que encontré para evitar que se bloqueen los objetos en el margen superior izquierdo, es desactivando esa opción que marque en la imagen, luego puedo mover todo libremente, y no me bloquea la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al inicio tuve los mismos problemas, mis soluciones  son 3.

1. Reinicia el programa, y revisa si hay actualizaciones pendiente al iniciarlo de nuevo.
2. Una solución es cambiar el archivo `android/gradle scrpt/build.grade`

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'

cambiar la segunda implementación y variarla, entre 0.0

3. Existe algo llamado tema de la aplicación que aveces cambia, es un problema de la api anterior pero puede funcionarte :

cambiaremos el style del xml `res/values/styles`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Agregamos el “BASE” y se arregla el error enc aso de mostrarse.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

4. esta solución no es tan practica pero puedes que reinicies el SDK se arregle el problema
   te dejo un video tutorial que guarde donde quizas te ayude 
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gR-nQVTgYi8